# How to calculate x percent of a cell.Value, using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("r01").Value = 100
x = 10
Range("r02").Value = x percentage of "r01" // should be 10 in this case
```

x is a dynamically changed variable.
How can I calculate an x percent of a cell.Value, using vba ?

Comment: How would you do it with pen and paper?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about calculating a percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```
Range("r01").Value = 100
x = 10
Range("r02").Value = x / 100 * Range("r01").Value
```